# MySQL Join Three Tables, Count, and Get The Last Username

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have a problem with sql query. I need join three tables, count rows, get last row, and the create custom column.
The example my tables like below:

table name: **article**

```
_______________________________________
idarticle     idwriter     title
---------------------------------------
1             1            Title One
2             3            Title Two
3             2            Title Three
```

table name: **comment**

```
________________________________________________________________________________
idcomment     idarticle     idcommented     content          datetime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             1             2               Comment One      2015-05-15 00:00:00
2             1             3               Comment Two      2015-05-16 00:00:00
3             1             1               Comment Three    2015-05-17 00:00:00
4             2             2               Comment Four     2015-05-18 00:00:00
5             3             3               Comment Five     2015-05-19 00:00:00
6             3             2               Comment Six      2015-05-20 00:00:00
```

table name: **member**

```
_____________________
idmember     username
---------------------
1            apple
2            orange
3            banana
```

How to join all tables, count, and get last commented+username with one query.
May the result like:

```
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
idarticle idwriter title       username_writer totalcomments lastcomment_id lastcomment_username lastcomment_datetime
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3         2        Title Three orange          2             2              orange               2015-05-20 00:00:00
2         3        Title Two   banana          1             2              orange               2015-05-18 00:00:00
1         1        Title One   apple           3             1              apple                2015-05-17 00:00:00
```

I hope someone will solve my problem.
I using PHP 5.4, MySQL 5.5, and MeekroDB library, so the query must support with those.
Sorry for my English.
Thank you

Comment: Is there an sqlfiddle?

Comment: why for `idarticle=3`  `lastcommentid=2` in expected result? in my mind it is `6`

Comment: @Alex - because it's not the last comment, but the last person to comment.

Comment: @Baron - side note, the most-recent-comment part is known as [tag:greatest-n-per-group].  This would be easier in an RDBMS that actually supported windowing functions.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/132336/1

```
SELECT a.idarticle, a.idwriter , a.title, 
       m.username, 
       c.idcomment, cm.username, c.datetime
FROM article a
LEFT JOIN member m
ON a.idwriter = m.idmember
LEFT JOIN comment c
ON a.idarticle = c.idarticle
LEFT JOIN comment c1
ON a.idarticle = c1.idarticle
  AND c.datetime<c1.datetime
LEFT JOIN member cm
ON c.idcommented = cm.idmember
WHERE c1.datetime IS NULL
```